# Why does private constructor prohibits a inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, default-constructor

I know two ways, which prohibit inheritance:

- make a final class
- announce a private constructor

To prevent the inheritance must the **default** constructor of the class announces as private.

```
class Class {
    private Class() {}    
}

class OtherClass extends Class {
    // Error! There is no default constructor available
}
```

Did everything done for using `super`?

```
class Class {
    public Class() {}
}

class OtherClass extends Class {
    public OtherClass() { super(); } // Did everything done for this opportunity?
}
```

I want to know why you can not inherit from a class with private default constructor and what is conditioned by?

Comment: What do you mean by "Did everything done for using super"?

Comment: Of course you can inherit from a class with a private constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, if you create an instance of `Child Class`, `Parent Class` instance gets created implicitly. 
So `Parent Class` constructor should be visible to `Child Class` as it calls the constructor of `Parent Class` constructor using `super()` in the first statement itself.

So if you change the constructor of the `Parent Class` to `private`, `Child Class` could not access it and could not create any instance of its own, so compiler on the first hand just does not allow this at all.

But if you want to `private` default constructor in `Parent Class`, then you need to explicitly create an overloaded `public` constructor in the `Parent Class` & then in `Child class` constructor you need to call using `super(param)` the public overloaded constructor of `Parent Class` .

Moreover, you might think then what's the use of `private` constructors. `private` constructors is mostly used when you don't want others from any external class to call `new()` on your class. So in that case, we provide some `getter()` method to provide out class's `object`.In that method you can create/use existing Object of your class & return it from that method.

Eg. `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();`. This actually forms the basis of `Singleton` design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether it's the default constructor or not.  If all constructors for a class are private, then none of its subtypes could have valid constructors, because all constructors must invoke constructors for the supertype.